# Yii - getting the attributes from a model

Tags: php, oop, yii, frameworks

I have a model that has data set dynamically using the following:

```
$array = array('user_id' => 12345);
$model->setAttributes($array);
```

But when I run the following on the next line down it returns null?

```
echo $model->user_id; // i would expect to see 12345
```

Can anyone explain why this is null?

Comment: Are you sure user_id is a `safe` attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setAttributes` will only work on attributes that have rules set on it. If there is no rule set for the attribute `user_id`, then you need to put it under `safe` rule. This is related to [Massive Assignment](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/161/understanding-safe-validation-rules/).

Answer (score -1):

```
$array = array('user_id' => 12345);
$model->setAttributes($array);
```

This one define the  model

```
echo $model->user_id;
```

is printing the record from database having column name user_id.

```
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm(); ?>

<?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($model,'username'); ?>

<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
```

This code only printing the label which you defined "12345"

The "NULL" returns, possibily there is no data in the column

Comment: `echo $model->user_id;` would print the current value of user_id of the model instance.